# Why are the GWT web applications are opened in port 8888 instead of 8080

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gwt

I am using eclipse and I have configured Tomcat in eclipse,I start the service by makimg use of startup.bat file of the server and I open tomcat home page in browser , as Tomcat is running on port 8080 everything works fine in this case & also when I run any web application from eclipse, but when I run a GWT application from the eclipse the application is opened on port 8888.

I have checked the tomcat configuration in eclipse and the port of tomcat is 8080 itself in server.xml as well as in the configuration settings which you can see by double clicking on the existing server

My doubt is why are GWT applications opened on port 8888 instead of 8080, also if I want can I change something and make the GWT applications work on port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Tomcat on port 8080 and Jetty on 8888.
You have deployed your gwt application in jetty. That is why your application is runnung on port 8888.
To run your app in Tomcat, copy and paste contents of your WebRoot folder into the webapps folder of your tomcat. Then you can run it in your tomcat on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port that is used when you run GWT application in Eclipse on the Run (or Debug) Configurations screen, on the "Server" tab. The default port is 8888, but you can change this if you wish. I find that using the option to automatically select an unused port works best.

Here's a screen capture from the run configuration:

[image: Run Configuration]

And here's the Development Mode URL:

[image: Development Mode URL]

Comment: In the server tab the port number of apche tomcat is 8080 itself. in when you run a GWT application you get a Development Mode there I can see it using port 8888, if I go back and check in server tab the tomcat is using port 8080 itself.

Comment: If possible, please add screen captures of what you are seeing (I've added them for my system).

Answer (score 0):

You are deploying your application in Jetty. 
To deploy in TomCat:

1. Add project to TomCat
2. Run As/ Run Configurations/ Server - Uncheck Run buillt-in server.
3. Click Run
4. In url change port 8888 to 8080 and open in browser.
5. Enjoy you app running on TomCat!